# Google Drive File Resource is missing permissions data

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

I'm using the ruby sdk for Google Drive, API v2. When using the `files.list` or `files.get` method, the response does not contain `permissions`. [The documentation indicates that it should](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files):

`permissions[]` `list`  `The list of permissions for users with access to this file.`

I am able to fetch the permissions in a separate API call (`permissions.list` with `fileId`). This indicates to me that the client has the correct permissions to see this information, but for some reason the API is not returning it with the `files.list` or `files.get` calls.

**Is there something I need to do to ensure the permissions field is present when using the `files.list` call?** I would very much like to avoid turning a (N/PageSize) problem in to an N problem.

Note: I have omitted including the relevant code and responses because they are pretty much as expected, except for `permissions`. For example, the `userPermission`, and `owners` attributes are present.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This property is not set by default, but you can explicitly call for it in the request url. You will have to rely on 'partial response', in which you can set the desired parameters to consult or list. You can read more on the subject here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/performance#partial-response; and the implementation for ruby can be found on this site: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/performance#fields

Comment: _"This property is not set by default"_ - source? Both of those links you posted state _"By default, the server sends back the **full representation** of a resource after processing requests."_ Emphasis mine.